# Use KDE wallet to authenticate a mount call

Tags: mount, kde, password, samba, kwallet

I am using a command similar to the following to mount some NAS samba shares in my Kubuntu 18.04 system:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o "username=MyUser" //MyServer/MyFolder ~/SharedFolders/MyFolder
```

This works fine. However it asks for the password every time. I would like to use the KDE password wallet (or some similar agent) for authentication.

I want the password being asked at the GUI a single time, then it should be stored permanently and reused for future `mount` calls.

Is something like that possible with `mount`?

If not, is there an automatable alternative in KDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to tell `mount` which program to use for storing/reading passwords, but there are a few KDE tools you can combine to automate the process.

For storing/reading passwords: `kwalletcli`
For a GUI password prompt: `kdialog`
You should be able to install them with your package manager.

[I wrote a script](https://gitlab.com/snippets/2006861) that does this (with a few extra options). It should be doing everything you asked for: if the password does not exist, a GUI prompt is shown (if available) and the password is stored in a wallet for later use.

You can update the password from the command line with `kwalletcli` again, but the only way I could find to delete them is the KWalletManager GUI app.

Here's the script as of 2020-08-22:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

usage() {
    echo "Usage: $0 [-u username] [-o options] share mount"
    echo
    echo "Defaults for optional parameters:"
    echo
    echo "  username:  the output of 'id -un', i.e. the current user"
    echo "  options:   defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8"
    echo "             Pass an empty string to clear default options"
    exit 2
}

while getopts "u:o:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        u) USERNAME="$OPTARG" ;;
        o) OPTIONS="$OPTARG" ;;
        *) usage ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

[ "$#" -ne 2 ] && usage

# Mount settings
USERNAME="${USERNAME:-$(id -un)}"
OPTIONS="${OPTIONS-defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8}"
SHARE="$1"
MOUNT="$2"

# Wallet settings
FOLDER="CIFS credentials"
ENTRY="$USERNAME@${SHARE#//}"

read_password() {
    PASS_PROMPT="Password for $USERNAME@${SHARE#//}: "

    if command -v kdialog >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        PASSWORD="$(kdialog --password "$PASS_PROMPT")"
    else
        # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28393320/6702490
        trap 'stty echo' EXIT
        stty -echo
        printf "%s" "$PASS_PROMPT"
        read -r PASSWORD
        printf "\n"
        stty echo
        trap - EXIT
    fi
}

if ! PASSWORD="$(kwalletcli -f "$FOLDER" -e "$ENTRY" 2>/dev/null)"; then
    if read_password && [ -n "$PASSWORD" ]; then
        kwalletcli -f "$FOLDER" -e "$ENTRY" -p "$PASSWORD"
    else
        echo "Empty/no password entered, skipping writing password to wallet and mount."
        exit 1
    fi
fi

sudo mount -t cifs -o "${OPTIONS}${OPTIONS:+,}username=$USERNAME,password=$PASSWORD" "$SHARE" "$MOUNT"
```

> Note: using `kwallet-query` would be the better option since it comes bundled with KDE/kwallet and supports non-default wallets, but I wasn't able to make it store a password. There were no errors shown and no non-zero exit code, but the password wouldn't be written to the wallet.

Comment: I tried to use the script in the university. I think I can not use the mount method there since user are not sudo-ers.