# Open smb drive mounted through dolphin in terminal

Tags: nautilus, samba, dolphin

At my workplace we have a shared network drive.
I usually mount the network drive through Nautilus, but I'm honestly not very happy with Nautilus.
This means that I would like to change from Nautilus to Dolphin, where actual features are present.

My problem is that while Nautilus mounts the drive `/run/user/1000/gvfs/drivename` I cannot find the drive location when mounting in Dolphin.

I would really like to have the drive accessible through the terminal. While I can open Nautilus solely for the purpose of mounting this drive, it's more than a bit annoying.

Do you have any idea about how I open the drive in terminal after mounting it through dolphin?

Comment: Is mounting using `cifs-utils` via `fstab` an option ? [Read this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot/157140#157140).

Comment: I have never gotton this to work before, Guess I got better at linuxing now (I have tried it) Do you know if i can pull the credentials from somewhere safer than a file? like suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187384/use-kde-wallet-to-authenticate-a-mount-call

Comment: What about nemo?

Comment: @guillermochamorro where does that mount the drive? in the same place as nautilus?

Comment: @pLumo I have no such thing. that's why I would like to pull them from somewhere else. For now I have just removed the password, that seems okay (although cifs seem to show the password length, which is slightly annoying)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen oh, I'm not sure, I was suggesting a possibility, sorry.

Comment: @guillermochamorro No problem ;-) I'm not opposed to trying out nemo at some point, but I'm also not sure wether it has all the functionality I'm looking for (anything is better than Nautilus though)